# HP Omni 27-1027c AIO...Upgradeable?

Tags: graphics-card, upgrade

I just bought an HP Omni 27 1057c from Sams Club. I like it a lot, but I want more performance. discovered that the integrated Intel HD 2500 graphics is almost useless for most games. I found a website that says it can be upgraded at http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2398314,00.asp. The computers specs can be found at Sams Club website or at HP website [HP Product Specs](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c03377747&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=101&contentType=SupportFAQ&prodSeriesId=5186974&prodTypeId=12454).

So what do you think? Can I upgrade Motherboard and Video Card?

Answer (score 0):

Sort of - from the HP specs, If you can find [a MXM card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_PCI_Express_Module) of the same 'type', you should be able to add on a better video adaptor, and it will need to be a [MXM 3.0 version: Type A](http://www.mxm-upgrade.com/Tech_30.html) fitting the specs mentioned on the HP product specs with an output of 35W. The cards are standard, but using one of the models that HP has used will be a safer bet.

If you can find one, and it works, upgrading the video adaptor is just that. AIWs are pretty much laptop-grade parts so, I don't see any major advantage to upgrading the motherboard.